# LESS - import another file from URL

Tags: css, visual-studio, less, config

I've seen I can import another less file from URL,
with the @import command
(e.g. `@import (reference) "https://s3-us2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/18728/pure.less"`)

But - I want it to be **configurable**.
I'm working with Visual Studio and I have a parent solution who contains my less file,
I want to use this file in his children solutions but I can't do it with relative path (the compile will be failed because the file not exists in the child solution), so it seems like my only way to do it it's importing through URL.

My problem with importing by URL, is to change the URL according to the environment (dev/qa/prod etc.) I want it to config somewhere the environments so the LESS file will 'know' to get the right value.

Eventually, I want it to be something like:
`@import (reference) "https://web.<environment>.com/pure.less"`

Of course  should be kind of variable.

I hope you understand my problem.

Comment: what are you using on server side? perhaps you are looking for some spaguetti <%= csspath %>

Comment: I'm using C#, but the <%= csspath %> should be inside the LESS file and I dont think I can do it

Answer (score 3):

In case your configuration variable is a LESS variable that can be accessed when calling the import statement, you could simply use [variable interpolation in the import statement](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-import-statements):

```
@import "settings"; // this is where @environment: "dev"; is set
@import (reference) "https://web.@{environment}.com/pure.less";
```

Comment: actuallity I want to get the enviorment value from config file, as web.config, can I do it somehow?

Comment: Hmm, at least this is not a built-in feature of LESS. Probably you would have to write a script that reads the web.config and creates the above settings-file with the required LESS variables before compiling the LESS to CSS.